# I cannot use the uploaded Android library, perhaps because classes.jar is empty

Tags: android, gradle, jar, android-jetpack-compose, maven-central

I recently published the following Android library for Jetpack Compose to Maven Central for the first time.
https://github.com/sanao1006/compose-duck

However, when I actually added this library to a dependency in another project, it was empty and could not be used.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mGAl.png)

Why is this, is it because there is something wrong with the build.gradle.kts settings...
I used nexus repository manager.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me the cause.

I want my uploaded Android library to be available.